# image-magic: combining images to the table

Tags: images, imagemagick

I use convert utility of image-magic to combine several images producing one big summary chart, with all initial images joinded in a single row:

```
convert "${vizu}"/img_*.png +append "${vizu}"/summary.png
```

is it possible to obtain the same kind of the combined file, where the initial images would be organized in three rows ? For example for 12 images it should be 3x4 table

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to obtain a combined file, where the initial images would be organized in three rows? For example, for 12 images it should be 3x4 table.

You don't specify the image dimensions, but theoretically you could try using [montage](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) e.g.:

```
magick montage "${vizu}"/img_*.png -tile 3x4 -geometry +0+0 "${vizu}"/summary.png
```

`montage` works best if the images are all the same size or follow a regular pattern for the given layout i.e. 3x4 (e.g. they were sliced from the same image).

Comment: For 3 rows and an unknown number of columns, use `-tile x3`. For 3 columns and an unknown number of rows, use `-tile 3x`.